# How to extract columns of data from a flask-sqlalchemy query in a form that can be used with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using the results of a flask-sqlalchemy query to plot data in matplotlib. I have some working code, but it is inelegant and inefficient. I would like to be able to get multiple columns of data from a single query, in a form that I can use in matplotlib. I'm new to Python (using v3.4) and I don't really 'get' it yet. At the moment I am querying the database once for each column of data.

All help gratefully received.

```
# views.py

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from .models import Sensor

def DrawChart():
    #  Draw a chart
    x = Sensor.query.with_entities(Sensor.UnixTime).filter(Sensor.UnixTime >= config.startDateTime).filter(
        Sensor.UnixTime <= config.endDateTime).all()
    y1 = Sensor.query.with_entities(Sensor.SupplyVoltage).filter(Sensor.UnixTime >= config.startDateTime).filter(
        Sensor.UnixTime <= config.endDateTime).all()
    y2 = Sensor.query.with_entities(Sensor.TotalCurrent).filter(Sensor.UnixTime >= config.startDateTime).filter(
        Sensor.UnixTime <= config.endDateTime).all()

    # Draw the chart
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x, y1, 'k--')
    ax.plot(x, y2, 'ro')

# models.py

from . import db

db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)

class Sensor(db.Model):
    """Sensor model links to sensor data table for displaying data and feeding MatPlotLib"""
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['sensorReadings']

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Sensor model'


# __INIT__.py

from flask import Flask
from flask_sslify import SSLify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('Agg')  # Stops errors when maplotlob tries to use X-windows backend

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)  # Use Flask instance folders to keep some settings out of GIT.
app.config.from_object('config')  # Main config file
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')  # Instance config file

sslify = SSLify(app)  # Force Flask to use SSL i.e. HTTPS
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)  # Initialize encryption for hashing passwords
db = SQLAlchemy(app)  # Initialize SQLite database
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should worry about the inefficiency of having multiple queries. However, you can indeed make it more *elegant*, taking care of this problem for example: what if one of those queries breaks?

I'd suggest you keep all 3 separate queries but envelope them inside try/except statements, so that if one query fails you will get to know which one. It will help you with debugging and you can also prompt the user with appropriate feedback, which improves user experience.

Here's a sample:

```
    def DrawChart():
        #  Draw a chart
        try:
            x = Sensor.query.with_entities(Sensor.UnixTime).filter(
                Sensor.UnixTime >= config.startDateTime 
                and Sensor.UnixTime <= config.endDateTime
            ).all()
        except:
            # Throw some error
            print "error1"

        try:
            y1 = Sensor.query.with_entities(Sensor.SupplyVoltage).filter(
                Sensor.UnixTime >= config.startDateTime 
                and Sensor.UnixTime <= config.endDateTime
            ).all()
        except:
            print "error2"

        try:
            y2 = Sensor.query.with_entities(Sensor.TotalCurrent).filter(
                Sensor.UnixTime >= config.startDateTime 
                and Sensor.UnixTime <= config.endDateTime
            ).all()
        except:
            print "error3"

        # Draw the chart
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.plot(x, y1, 'k--')
        ax.plot(x, y2, 'ro')
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. I'll implement the error handling. All the best!